# i have error in query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, query, c#

i am not getting what is the issue in the query probably i am not following the correct way to put the string and char sign , i am inserting the data in c# to local host with where clause please check the query and Error i am getting

```
String insertQuery = "insert into exam_add (id,session_id,Title,From_date,To_date,class_id,is_Post,is_Lock) select '"+id+ ",s.session,'" + title.Text+",'"+ from.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+",'"+to.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+ ", c.class_name,'"+x+",'"+x+" from year_session s, classes c where s.id = '1' and c.id='" + cls + "'";
```

**Error**

[image: y]

Comment: Please don't build up SQL statements like this. You're making yourself vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: And please do provide the actual SQL string.

Comment: Dates need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

If you add static strings to your SELECT Statement you always have to surround them on both sides with single ticks.

But you should urgently consider **prepared statements** like
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.8

```
String insertQuery = "insert into exam_add
  (id,session_id,Title,From_date,To_date,class_id,is_Post,is_Lock) 
select 
   '"+id+ "'
   ,s.session
   ,'" + title.Text+"'
   ,'"+ from.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"'
   ,'"+to.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+ "'
   , c.class_name
   ,'"+x+"'
   ,'"+x+"' 
 from year_session s, classes c 
 where s.id = '1' and c.id='" + cls + "'";
```